# Looping in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to loop in Oracle on monthly basis for 3 years. I am trying for daily basis first and below is my query but not sure about the error.

can you please help with this. I am fairly new to oracle.

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATE;

SET @StartDT =  '20090101'

WHILE @StartDT <= '20090131'
BEGIN
    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@StartDT) + '---' + convert(varchar,DATEADD(DAY,1,@StartDT))
END
```

Answer (score 2):

What you posted is completely SQL Server syntax.  In Oracle, you'd probably do this in SQL

```
select date '2009-01-01' + level
  from dual
connect by level <= 31
```

If you want to use PL/SQL (and assuming you are using a tool that will display the output from `dbms_output` which you shouldn't assume will happen in prod), you could do something like this.

```
declare
  l_dt date := date '2009-01-01';
begin
  while( l_dt <= date '2009-01-31' )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( to_char( l_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) );
    l_dt := l_dt + 1;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can use `for loop` as following:

```
Begin
For d in (select date '2009-01-01' + level - 1 as dt
from dual
Connect by level <= add_months(date '2009-01-01', 3) - date '2009-01-01')
Loop
dbms_output.put_line(to_char(d.dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
End loop;
End;
/
```

Cheers!!